# Using XML PATH to concatenate multiple fields

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm having a bit of trouble implementing the XML PATH method of concatenating multiple rows. So, given the following table, **Test**.

```
ID  Type  
 1  boy
 2  boy
 3  boy
 1  girl
 2  girl
 3  man
 3  woman
```

The query is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.ID,
    (
        SELECT  b.Type + ','
        FROM Test as b
        WHERE a.Type = b.Type
        for XML PATH ('')
    )
FROM Test as a
```

but instead of returning:

```
ID  Type  
 1  boy,girl,man,
 2  boy,girl,
 3  boy,girl,woman
```

it instead returns this:

```
ID  Type
 1  boy,boy,boy,
 1  girl,girl,
 2  boy,boy,boy,
 2  girl,girl,
 3  boy,boy,boy,
 3  man,
 3  woman,
```

What's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're joining on the wrong field.

Try

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.ID,
    (
        SELECT  b.Type + ','
        FROM Test as b
        WHERE a.ID = b.ID
        for XML PATH ('')
    )
FROM Test as a
```

Comment: Indeed I am! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using DISTINCT prefer using `GROUP BY` something like this...

```
SELECT  a.ID,

   STUFF((SELECT  ', ' +  [Type] [text()]
          FROM Test 
          WHERE ID = a.[ID]
          for XML PATH (''),TYPE).
          value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,2,'') AS [Type]

FROM Test as a
GROUP BY a.ID
```

Comment: @lunarplasma Yes certainly using group by instead of DISTINCT can give you much better performance.